# Error launching SDK manager: "find_java.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running"

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I am trying to start the android sdk manager in android studio, but it shows me the following error

https://plus.google.com/u/0/113311995935504360295/posts/h5EKzabisQj?pid=6068461235610543378&oid=113311995935504360295

> Cannot launch SDK manager
>
> Output:
>
> This version of C:\PROGRA~1\Android\ANDROI~1\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.
>
> ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.

As for the error message, In my system I have 32-bit java sdk1.7, 32-bit OS, already setup my JAVA_HOME variable to the java installation path, still it shows the same error. 
In another system, I have 64-bit configuration, It works well, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the help guys. I just upgraded my windows to a 64bit version. Updated the JDK to a 64bit version. Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Just fixed the same issue. The SDK Manager is now opening without any issue at my end.

> Solution 1 (working fine): Download the find_java.exe file from
>   previous (working) SDK. Link: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9im85Cl0QPaV3ZkeWI0dkRVNnc/view?usp=sharing) Paste & replace the file you downloaded to %ProgramFiles%\\tools\lib\
>
> Solution 2: Download the previous SDK and replace it with current version.
>   Link: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe
>
> Solution 3: In /tools/android.bat  set java_exe =
>   %ProgramFiles%\\bin\java.exe comment out REM call
>   lib\find_java.bat

Answer (score 1):

You don't say in your question, but it sounds like you have recently updated your SDK to 23.0.4. If that's the case, there's a bug in the release documented here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77289

The bug is that there was a bad version of the `find_java.exe` utility shipped with that version. This is fixed in 23.0.5, which is out now.

As a different workaroud you can either replace that utility from a previous version of the SDK, or you can copy the `find_java.exe` linked to from comment #11 in the bug:

http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe

into the `tools\lib\` directory in your SDK.

Comment: Just had the same problem as OP, I have substituted find_java.exe to version from 23.0.2 and manager started properly. Afer that I was given possibility to update to 23.0.5, I have done that and now its all ok. After installing 23.0.4 manager is asking user for closing manager and starting it again - the problem is that it actually won't start again.

Answer (score 0):

When I used windows, I had a similiar error. First off you should check watchfully JAVA_HOME path. If you are sure that your JAVA_HOME path maybe two different jdk is installed on your computer. You match your JAVA_HOME and jdk path of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue reported above ( https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77289 ), returned with the r24 version bundle in Android Studio 1.0

The bug is in tools\lib\find_java.bat, just below these lines

```
reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" |^
find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64
```

add the correct instruction for your system,  for example

```
set arch_ext=32
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 issue in find_java.bat

1. conflict with dos find and unix find.

   --> use findstr instead of find
2. miss setting "arch_ext"

   (currently arch_ext set to "32 " (space included))

   --> delete space after 32

Then you should

---

- find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64

+ findstr /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32|| set arch_ext=64

---